# Did my array go away or is the partion not mounting correctly after reboot

Tags: partition, fstab, raid, mdadm, automounting

I had created a raid-1 array for two drives (sde and sdf) using the normal mdadm process and had created it under md1 and mounted it to /mnt/storage.  After a reboot md1 no longer exists.  My /mnt/plex works fine. Did my array go away or do I just need to point the partition to the correct mount point?

Running `lsblk` gives me

```
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINTS
loop0         7:0    0  63.4M  1 loop  /snap/core20/1974
loop1         7:1    0  63.5M  1 loop  /snap/core20/2015
loop2         7:2    0  40.8M  1 loop  /snap/snapd/19993
loop3         7:3    0 111.9M  1 loop  /snap/lxd/24322
loop4         7:4    0  40.8M  1 loop  /snap/snapd/20092
sda           8:0    1   7.3T  0 disk
└─md0         9:0    0  21.8T  0 raid5 /mnt/plex
sdb           8:16   1   7.3T  0 disk
└─md0         9:0    0  21.8T  0 raid5 /mnt/plex
sdc           8:32   1   7.3T  0 disk
└─md0         9:0    0  21.8T  0 raid5 /mnt/plex
sdd           8:48   1   7.3T  0 disk
└─md0         9:0    0  21.8T  0 raid5 /mnt/plex
sde           8:64   0   3.6T  0 disk
sdf           8:80   0   3.6T  0 disk
nvme0n1     259:0    0 931.5G  0 disk
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0     1G  0 part  /boot/efi
└─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0 930.5G  0 part  /
```

Running `blkid` gives me

```
/dev/nvme0n1p1: UUID="255C-50C9" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="26565297-8615-4534-88b8-a160ab111fe4"
/dev/nvme0n1p2: UUID="ac32d63a-e8dc-4f58-b677-507491ed46de" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="25fa09fa-6781-49bf-927c-89e721f71154"
/dev/sdd: UUID="8051a9fa-3272-6a40-3950-5897a2b600f4" UUID_SUB="cb838ac3-6c2a-bfb0-fd0d-f7c63c447aa3" LABEL="tron:0" TYPE="linux_raid_member"
/dev/sdb: UUID="8051a9fa-3272-6a40-3950-5897a2b600f4" UUID_SUB="e4209087-7804-1e66-c3d2-dfef0f898b73" LABEL="tron:0" TYPE="linux_raid_member"
/dev/md0: UUID="f81c3ae4-363f-453a-ab49-1e716b27fc3b" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/sdc: UUID="8051a9fa-3272-6a40-3950-5897a2b600f4" UUID_SUB="f8da02fe-22e3-6f55-880d-c1d52c78167e" LABEL="tron:0" TYPE="linux_raid_member"
/dev/sda: UUID="8051a9fa-3272-6a40-3950-5897a2b600f4" UUID_SUB="d6bfc2f7-056d-441a-023f-25d73804c456" LABEL="tron:0" TYPE="linux_raid_member"
/dev/loop1: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop4: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop2: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop3: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/sdf: PTUUID="e6979b33-6f82-11ea-96f0-0026b98cb28a" PTTYPE="gpt"
/dev/sde: PTUUID="e6a40000-6f82-11ea-96f0-0026b98cb28a" PTTYPE="gpt"
```

And here is what's in my `/etc/fstab` Note: I uncommented the last two lines because it was causing a timeout issue, which uncommenting helped and it doesn't hang, but this is probably part of the issue

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p2 during curtin installation
/dev/disk/by-uuid/ac32d63a-e8dc-4f58-b677-507491ed46de / ext4 defaults 0 1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during curtin installation
/dev/disk/by-uuid/255C-50C9 /boot/efi vfat defaults 0 1
/swap.img       none    swap    sw      0       0
/dev/md0 /mnt/plex ext4 defaults,nofail,discard 0 0
#UUID=489c654c-58e8-4187-b478-b37bc6af81f9 /mnt/storage auto defaults,x-parent=f87a9a2f:b87b822b:60dc9e96:9d59d84f 0 0
#UUID=489c654c-58e8-4187-b478-b37bc6af81f9 /mnt/storage auto defaults,x-parent=f87a9a2f:b87b822b:60dc9e96:9d59d84f 0 0
```

If I don't uncomment the last two lines I get the following [timed out waiting for device](https://imgur.com/a/KOlDsrd)

Comment: According to blkid, there's a GPT partition table on sde, sdf. So it's possible your mdadm metadata was overwritten in the process of creating (or repairing) the GPT partition table. Data itself might still be undamaged if you can determine the correct offset. I recommend you use partitions for mdadm instead of bare drives for this exact reason, it's just too easy for accidents to happen otherwise.